# Simulating copula with copula::normalCopula: what is the covariance of output?

Tags: r, copula

I am trying to simulate data from a normal Copula using R's `copula` package, more precisely using `normalCopula` and then `mvdc`. I note that the function `normalCopula` wants the correlation matrix R, not the covariance S. Looking at the output, I note that while the `cor` of the sample is close to the population R, the `cov` of the simulated data is not close to my population S, even when rescaling by the S' variances?

So: what is the covariance of the output of `mvdc(copula=normalCopula(param=P2p(cov2cor(SIG)),...)`, if it is neither R nor (rescaled) S? I suspect the output covariance is a mix of the input correlation R and the marginal variances/moments? How should I rescale my data so that it has covariance S?

```r
library(copula)
S <- matrix(c(0.5, 0.8, 0.7, 0.8, 2, 0.2, 0.7, 0.2, 8), 3,3)
R <- cov2cor(S)

## Simulate data with cpula package
myCop <- normalCopula(param=P2p(R), dim = 3, dispstr = "un")
myMvd <- mvdc(copula=myCop, margins="gamma",
              marginsIdentical=TRUE,
              paramMargins=list(list(shape=2, scale=1)))
X_copula <- rMvdc(5000000, myMvd)

## check resulting cov?
cor(X_copula);R # yes, they seem to be close
#>           [,1]       [,2]       [,3]
#> [1,] 1.0000000 0.78346901 0.32660893
#> [2,] 0.7834690 1.00000000 0.04496475
#> [3,] 0.3266089 0.04496475 1.00000000
#>      [,1] [,2] [,3]
#> [1,] 1.00 0.80 0.35
#> [2,] 0.80 1.00 0.05
#> [3,] 0.35 0.05 1.00
X_copula_rescale <- X_copula%*% diag(sqrt(diag(S))) # rescale by vaariance
cov(X_copula_rescale);S # far!?
#>          [,1]      [,2]       [,3]
#> [1,] 0.999889 1.5666511  1.3075266
#> [2,] 1.566651 3.9989791  0.3599924
#> [3,] 1.307527 0.3599924 16.0285098
#>      [,1] [,2] [,3]
#> [1,]  0.5  0.8  0.7
#> [2,]  0.8  2.0  0.2
#> [3,]  0.7  0.2  8.0
cov(X_copula_rescale)/2;S
#>           [,1]      [,2]      [,3]
#> [1,] 0.4999445 0.7833255 0.6537633
#> [2,] 0.7833255 1.9994895 0.1799962
#> [3,] 0.6537633 0.1799962 8.0142549
#>      [,1] [,2] [,3]
#> [1,]  0.5  0.8  0.7
#> [2,]  0.8  2.0  0.2
#> [3,]  0.7  0.2  8.0
```

<sup>Created on 2023-03-13 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: FWIW, this experiment behaves as expected when I use normal marginals. Are you sure that `cor(X_copula)` should estimate `R` when using gamma marginals? It doesn't seem to be a very good estimate here, considering the sample size ...

Comment: my question is, which covariance of the copula should I expect? `cor` clearly gives me something very close to R, but how does cov of X relate to R and to the original S I wanted?